# typescript optional parameter type check

Tags: typescript

I've got a function (func) on a class (MyClass) with an optional parameter. The type of the optional parameter (MyInterface) has only optional properties.

I expected a compiler error when I call foo with a primitive like a number. But thats not the case. Why is it like that? And is there a way to tell the type system to mark that as an error?

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo?: string
}

class MyClass {
    func(b?: MyInterface) : void {}
}

let c = new MyClass();
c.func();
c.func({ foo: 'bar' });
c.func({ foo: 30 });       // compiler error: OK
c.func({});
c.func(60);                // No compiler error: Not what I expect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `number` is compatible with `{}`. (for example, imagine an argument of type `{toFixed: (n: number) => string}`, that too, is compatible with `number`).

You can also think about it this way: *you can do anything with a number, that you could with a `{foo?: string}`*.

Comment: Sounds like duck typing. Does TypeScript does kind of duck typing? In contrast to i.e. java where also an empty class is different from another empty class.

Comment: Yes, objects don't need to actually, explicitly implement an interface to belong to that interface. The properties just need to match. Note that with the `MyInterface` requirement, you won't be able to treat that `60` as a number inside of `MyClass.prototype.func`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce some dirty console.log-debugging:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo?: string
}

class MyClass {
    func(b?: MyInterface): void {
        console.log(`b:${b}`);
        if (b != undefined) {
            console.log(`b.foo:${b.foo}`);
        }
    }
}

let c = new MyClass();
c.func();
c.func({ foo: 'bar' });
c.func({ foo: 30 });       // compiler error: OK
c.func({});
c.func(60);                // No compiler error: Not what I expect
```

Results are:

```
b:undefined

b:[object Object]
b.foo:bar

b:[object Object]
b.foo:30

b:[object Object]
b.foo:undefined

b:60
b.foo:undefined
```

Let's focus on the last two results.

`MyInterface` has only `foo` parameter, which is moreover optional. So actually anything is of type `MyInterface`. That's why parameter `b` has value 60. `b` is in this case of type `MyInterface` without optional `foo` member.

If you remove optional operator from `foo` member then compiler will throw the exception. It will do the same if you add additional, non optional parameter to `MyInterface`.

Maybe it seems counter-intuitive but it's not. In the form you presented, the `MyInterface` doesn't define anything. You ask compiler to guard input to have `foo` parameter... or not have it. So why should it check if input is `object`?